# What will induce this pandas error while using df.update() ? Shape of passed values is (5624095, 10), indices imply (2322036, 10)

Tags: python, pandas

I got:

```
df1.shape: 51616 rows × 1 columns

df2.shape: 2322026 rows × 10 columns
```

After I do:

```
df2.update(df1)
```

I got error:

```
Shape of passed values is (5624095, 10), indices imply (2322036, 10)
```

What is wrong with my data?

Comment: You have different row count. df.update requires both dataframe to have equal row count

Comment: accroding to the document, they can be different. 
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2],
                   'B': [400, 500]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6],
                       'C': [7, 8, 9]})
df.update(new_df)

Comment: could you let me know the documentation that you are referring? I have [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

Comment: you could try my code in the comment. it works fine.

Comment: looks like your code works. But cant help you without more information. Is both df1 and df2 dataframe, because ```51616 rows × 1 columns``` could imply that you are updating on a series

Answer (score 0):

indices are duplicated.After reomved the duplicates, it works.