# ValueError indicating a mismatch between shape and indices when using df.update

Tags: python, pandas

So basically i'm trying to update the `Screening` column of the `file_change` dataframe into the value found in `df_duplicated` of the same `Screening` column name.

```
path_filtered_sample = Path(r"C:\Users\Experiment")
files_for_merging = path_filtered_sample.glob(f'**\*.csv')

df_duplicated = get_duplicated_df(df_filtered_merged) #User defined function that inputs some df to check for some discrepancy--in this case df_filtered_merged
df_duplicated = df_duplicated[['nid', 'Common Screening Value']].rename(columns={"Common Screening Value": 'Screening'})
df_duplicated.set_index('nid', inplace=True)

for file in files_for_merging:
    file_change = pd.read_csv(file)
    file_change.set_index('nid', inplace=True)
    file_change.update(df_duplicated)
    file_change.reset_index(inplace=True)
    file_change.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

The code works fine until somewhere along the loop where it would fail and give me a `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (788, 41), indices imply (787, 41)` after hitting the line `file_change.update(df_duplicated)` which is a little odd because there are only 787 rows in the `.csv` file excluding the headers. I also tried `file_change.shape` and it returns `(787,41)`. So I am not sure how the method came decided to say I passed 788 rows since the previous loops had no issues despite having the same format with headers as well. I checked `nid` column of the problematic file for duplicates and non were found as it was said to cause issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968616/what-will-induce-this-pandas-error-while-using-df-update-shape-of-passed-val).

It is a little hard to generate the reproducible output here as I don't know what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas concat: ValueError: Shape of passed values is blah, indices imply blah2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719407/pandas-concat-valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-blah-indices-imply-blah2)

Comment: Okay I checked the `nid` column of the "problematic file", but was not able to check if there were duplicates in the `df_duplicated`'s `nid` which I found there was 1 duplicate that caused the issue. Apparently I have to set both dataframes into a multi-index with `nid` being an argument together with another.